# Javascript function not being read from ejs html file in Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

In my html, I have a button that onClick calls a function with parameters that I pulled from my server side and passed it into this client page. I handle that onClick function with jquery located in a seperate .js file. I am adding the script tag (below) before my closing body tag. I know that I'm not referring to file incorrectly because all my other javascript functions work fine within the file..

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="../relative/path"></script>
```

When I go to click the button, it gives error saying "uncaught reference error function_name not defined"

Below is the html that has the button:

```html
<button onClick="twilio('<%= list[i].UserID %>')" class="btn btn-primary">Join</button>
```

And this is what my .js file looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function twilio(to_UID) {
    console.log("in here");
  };
  
});
```

HOWEVER: when I add the script inline in my html within script tags, it runs fine. I'd rather not do that to maintain good coding practices so plz help